# Smarty loop through values isnt returing the required value

Tags: php, smarty

Here is the dump of array, I want to access the values stored in "name" I can't seem to get that.

```
Array
(
[Main_photo] => listing_thumbnail16_10858051461322073003.jpg
[ID] => 16
[Kind_ID] => 1
[Account_ID] => 62
[Plan_ID] => 1
[Pay_date] => 2011-11-23 23:29:53
[Featured_ID] => 0
[Featured_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[Last_show] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[Crossed] => 
[Type] => sale
[Shows] => 3
[Status] => active
[Date] => 2011-11-23 23:29:53
[Rating] => 0
[Rating_votes] => 0
[Cron] => 0
[Cron_notified] => 0
[Cron_featured] => 0
[categories] => 
[headline] => asdasd
[price] => 12|euro
[description] => 
[condition] => 1
[title] => 
[lf_site_url] => 
[description_add] => 
[contact_number] => 
[Path] => automobiles
[Key] => automobiles
[Photos_count] => 1
[count_comments] => 0
[Featured] => 0
[name] => Automobiles
[fields] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Key] => headline
                [Type] => text
                [Default] => 
                [Condition] => 
                [Details_page] => 1
                [name] => Headline
                [value] => asdasd
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Key] => price
                [Type] => price
                [Default] => 
                [Condition] => 
                [Details_page] => 1
                [name] => Price
                [value] => € 12
            )

    )

[listing_title] => asdasd
)
Array
(
[Main_photo] => listing_thumbnail10_11485755481321487877.jpg
[ID] => 10
[Kind_ID] => 1
[Account_ID] => 9
[Plan_ID] => 1
[Pay_date] => 2011-11-17 04:57:45
[Featured_ID] => 22
[Featured_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[Last_show] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[Crossed] => 
[Type] => sale
[Shows] => 4
[Status] => active
[Date] => 2011-11-17 04:57:45
[Rating] => 0
[Rating_votes] => 0
[Cron] => 0
[Cron_notified] => 0
[Cron_featured] => 0
[categories] => 
[headline] => test
[price] => 1|euro
[description] => asdas
[condition] => 1
[title] => 
[lf_site_url] => 
[description_add] => 
[contact_number] => 
[Path] => automobiles
[Key] => automobiles
[Photos_count] => 1
[count_comments] => 0
[Featured] => 0
[name] => Automobiles
[fields] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Key] => headline
                [Type] => text
                [Default] => 
                [Condition] => 
                [Details_page] => 1
                [name] => Headline
                [value] => test
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Key] => price
                [Type] => price
                [Default] => 
                [Condition] => 
                [Details_page] => 1
                [name] => Price
                [value] => € 1
            )

    )

[listing_title] => test
)
```

What I am using at the moment is some thing like this:

```
{foreach from=$listings name='listings_check' item='listings_check'}
{foreach from=$listings_check item='check_array_for_name'}
{$check_array_for_name.name}
{/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

but this is not returning the required result can some one guide me.  Thanks in advance.

```
l 1 1 6 1 2 0 0 0 s 3 a 2 0 0 0 0 0 a 1 1 a a 1 0 0 A a l 1 1 9 1 2 2 0 0 s 4 a 2 0 0 0 0 0 t 1 a 1 a a 1 0 0 A t l 3 1 8 1 2 9 0 0 s 1 a 2 0 0 0 0 0 C 1 1 a a 1 2 0 A C l 2 1 1 1 2 1 0 0 s 7 a 2 0 0 0 0 0 C 1 t 1 a a 1 0 0 A C
```

Above is the output that is shown over there.

Comment: Could you tell us what it's returning instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your output, the foreach is looping over the items of each array, instead of over the arrays.

Concluding from your syntax of the foreach loop, I assume you are using smarty 2.x. In that case I would advise to remove the name attribute or at least rename it to something else than your item attribute as both will result in a variable. As they are currently named identically this means you will be accessing the foreach loop rather than the item.

See [the smarty docs on foreach](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl).

Comment: well as far as dump is concerned it is showing values from te result. But i will definitely see if there are some version issues w.r.t name and item syntax

Comment: Yeah you are pretty much helped me out. Still it wasnt the accurate answer but thx to your  suggestion i was able to find my own problem i simply modified my code to this  {foreach from=$listings name='listings_check' item='check_item'}

{$check_item.name}

{/foreach}  and i got the desired result.

Comment: @noobie-php ok great to hear that, glad I could help!

Comment: thx just for good's sake i am marking it true coz i have posted original answer in comments